# Filtering list in controller doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have application on AngularJs. 
I have variable in scope, which is initialized with data from API. `$scope.receivedRequests = CurrentUserData.incomeRequests();`

Cause request to API takes some time, `$scope.receivedRequests` is empty at start.

`$scope.receivedRequests` I've used with `ng-repeat`

```
<div class="full-row" ng-repeat="row in receivedRequests | filterByStatus:[State.PENDING] | partition:3 track by $index">
```

This data is also filtered. 
But when I tried to replace this filtering into controller, like

```
$scope.filterByStatus = function (statuses) {
        return $filter('filterByStatus')($scope.receivedRequests, statuses);
    };

    $scope.pendingRequests = $scope.filterByStatus([State.PENDING]);
```

`$scope.pendingRequests` were always empty.

How can I filter data in the controller?

---

```
.filter('filterByStatus', function () {
return function(arr, statuses) {
    if (!arr) { return; }
    return arr.filter(function(value) {
        return statuses.some(function(val) {
            return value.status == val;
        });
    });
};
```

});

`$scope.receivedRequests` is just array of elements, that have string property `status` (alos `id`, `date` etc.) as example : `status : "Pending"`

Comment: Can you share your filterByStatus filter code and your $scope.recievedRequests array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case I would use promises and split the code like this.

**Factory service**

```
app.factory('myService', function($http){
  return {
    getRequests: function(){
      return $http.get('http://someurl');
    }
  }
})
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myController', function(myService){

  $scope.filteredArray = [];

  myService.getRequests()
    .then( function(data){
      $scope.filteredArray = $scope.filterFunction(data);
    })

  $scope.filterFunction = function(array){
    //function logic
    //...
  }

})
```

**Notes:**

- The trick here is done by calling the filtering function inside the then() function. This way you are sure the data from the API is been already fetched and after that you can filter it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your $scope.recievedRequests object look, can you try the below... why don't you send the `State.pending` value with an associated `key` for your array.

```
$scope.filterByStatus = function (statuses) {
        return $filter('filterByStatus')($scope.receivedRequests, statuses);
};

$scope.pendingRequests = $scope.filterByStatus({key: State.PENDING})[0];
```

Comment: "with an associated key for your array" - Can you explain how this can help?

Comment: Is it possible to create a fiddle... you are filteringByStatus... why not pass it as ass array.. may be that's where your code is behaving in correctly.

Comment: From your updated post it seems State.PENDING is a string value with an associated key status, why not pass it as an object.